Lambda python dependecies packaging issues
Recently I am working on a project using Lambdas with python 3.11 runtime environment. so my project code structure is all the lambda code will be in the src/lambdaType/functionName.py and this project has the one utilities lambda layer. I am thinking of using all the python packages(requirements.txt) in the utilities folder and create a function around that required function from that package and use it in the lambda function by importing it. I can use the code from lambda layers into the lambda function by using sys.path.append('\opt')in the lambda function. I can also package the python dependencies into the lambda code if the requirements.txt file is in the src folder. so src/requirements.txt will be there. and src and utilities will be siblings directories. I am using the serverless framework template to deploy the lambdas. So my question now is i want to install python dependencies in the lambda layers? Can you please help me. I am checking the utilities.zip folder which is a lambda layer but the pythond dependencies are not there only the files are there.
service: client-plane

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.11
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-east-1'}
  tracing:
    apiGateway: true
    lambda: true
  deploymentPrefix: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
  apiGateway:
    usagePlan:
      quota:
        limit: 10000
        offset: 2
        period: MONTH
      throttle:
        burstLimit: 1000
        rateLimit: 500
  environment: ${file(./serverless/environments.yml)}

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    slim: true
    strip: false
    fileName: src/requirements.txt

package:
  individually: true
  patterns:
    - "!serverless/**"
    - "!.github/**"
    - "!tests/**"
    - "!package-lock.json"
    - "!package.json"
    - "!node_modules/**"

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-offline

layers:
  utilities:
    path: ./utilities
    description: utility functions
    compatibleRuntimes:
      - python3.11
    compatibleArchitectures:
      - x86_64
      - arm64
    package:
      include:
        - utilities/requirements.txt

functions:
  
  register:
      handler: src/auth/register.registerHandler
      name: register
      description: register a new user
      memorySize: 512
      timeout: 30 # in seconds api gateway has a hardtimelimit of 30 seconds
      provisionedConcurrency: 2
      tracing: Active
      architecture: arm64
      layers:
        - { Ref: UtilitiesLambdaLayer}
      events:
        - http:
            path: /register
            method: post
            cors: true
      vpc:
        securityGroupIds:
          - !Ref ClientPlaneLambdaSecurityGroup
        subnetIds:
          - !Ref ClientPlanePrivateSubnet1
          - !Ref ClientPlanePrivateSubnet2
      role: !GetAtt [LambdaExecutionWriteRole, Arn]
      

  login:
      handler: src/auth/login.loginHandler
      name: login
      description: login a user
      memorySize: 512
      timeout: 30 # in seconds api gateway has a hardtimelimit of 30 seconds
      provisionedConcurrency: 2
      tracing: Active
      architecture: arm64
      layers:
        - {Ref: UtilitiesLambdaLayer}
      events:
        - http:
            path: /login
            method: post
            cors: true
      vpc:
        securityGroupIds:
          - !Ref ClientPlaneLambdaSecurityGroup
        subnetIds:
          - !Ref ClientPlanePrivateSubnet1
          - !Ref ClientPlanePrivateSubnet2
      role: !GetAtt [LambdaExecutionReadRole, Arn]

resources:
  # Resources
  - ${file(./serverless/subnets.yml)}
  - ${file(./serverless/securitygroups.yml)}
  - ${file(./serverless/apigateway.yml)}
  - ${file(./serverless/cognito.yml)}
  - ${file(./serverless/databases.yml)}
  - ${file(./serverless/queues.yml)}
  - ${file(./serverless/IamRoles.yml)}

  # Outputs
  - ${file(./serverless/outputs.yml)}



I check some articles in aws so mostly in the lambda layer folder there should be a python folder which should have the python dependencies. but is there any docker container for the serverless framework whihc can do this automatically while deploying the code.  layer_content.zip
└ python
└ lib
└ python3.11
└ site-packages
└ requests
└ <other_dependencies> (i.e. dependencies of the requests package)
└ ...)
